# show global mediaelement to layoutroot?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I want to share `MediaElement` to play video among many pages (only 1 page will show video, others will play sound only).

```
<MediaElement x:Key="GlobalMedia" Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Stretch="Uniform" /> // static media element in App.xaml
```

If I dont show video, everything works so fine. However, when I try to add this `MediaElement` to `LayoutRoot`: `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(_media)`, I got `InvalideOperationSystem` exception (It told me that the mediaElement is already the child of another element). Does anyone has idea to show this global `MediaElement` to LayoutRoot? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the same code you added within the `LayoutRoot`?

Comment: @Kulasangar `MediaElement` is in `App.xaml`. I get it and add to `LayoutRoot` in Page constructor as: `_media = App.GlobalMediaElement;` and `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(_media);`.